# Sum up a column in Pandas DataFrame if a duplicate row exists

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, sum, duplicates, pandas-groupby

I have quite a large data set which looks similar to the below. This data set contains 10+ columns which will all have the same value, and then a 'Time' column which will contain unique values.

I am trying to sum up the time column, for each row that is duplicated, and do nothing with the ones that aren't.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'names':['Paul','George','Paul','John'],
                   'Time':[10,41,22,10],
                  'Date':['10/2/20', '10/1/20', '10/2/20','10/1/20']})
```

I've tried doing a groupby on all the columns which may contain duplicates and then sum up Time and reset the index, however the row count is less than what it should be when comparing it to a spreadsheet where this was done manually.

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: Please update the question with your expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC,

first we create a list of all your columns and remvoe `Time` from it, as this is the column we will be performing our operation on. The idea is to sum the values, if there is no duplication then the values will be the same, if there are duplicate names, as in Paul's case the values will be summed.

```
group_cols = df1.columns.tolist()
group_cols.remove('Time')

df2 = df1.groupby(group_cols,as_index=False)['Time'].sum()

print(df2)

    names     Date  Time
0  George  10/1/20    41
1    John  10/1/20    10
2    Paul  10/2/20    32
```